# Find the word and became sea's lord

Tags: riddle, word, crosswords

Find a word which by rearranging its letters, it **contains**:

- A city in Alaska
- A film where Chaplin's daughter performs
- A meteorical medical condition

> HINT: Solution word is 12 letters long (no dashes/spaces)
>
>  HINT: Subcontained words are 9 letters each

Comment: Sorry, English's not my first language: what is a *meteorical* medical condition?

Comment: Are you sure it is only *one* word?

Comment: This sure looks a lot like an [indirect anagram](https://cryptics.fandom.com/wiki/Indirect_anagram). Those are generally deemed "not fun" (see linked article), and especially without a letter counts or other limiting factors, they are highly ambiguous, as can be seen from the vastly different answer attempts posted. If this puzzle turns out to be something else instead (eg. a riddle, as the tags suggest), i'll make sure to retract my downvote.

Comment: You are right, I am amazed. Ill update the post and write a title that is a meaningful rhyme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

> OCEANOGRAPHY.

*A city in Alaska*

> [ANCHORAGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorage,_Alaska).

*A film where Chaplin's daughter performs*

> [*[The] ORPHANAGE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Orphanage_(2007_film)), starring Geraldine Chaplin.

*A meteorical medical condition*

> [AEROPHAGY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerophagia)? Thanks @MacGyver88 for getting this.

Comment: No problem. You did the hard parts. Great job :)

Comment: Absolutely great

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> Lemonade

A locality in Alaska

> [Nome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome,_Alaska)

A film where a Chaplin performs

> [One A.M.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_A.M._(1916_film))

A meteorical medical condition

> [Edema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edema) - which can be caused by [meteorism](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/meteorism)

Possible answer to also fit the title

> **Abodement** which could characterise the phrase "Live by the sword, die by the sword".

However, there are many possibilities here.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> **NEUROPHARMACOLOGIST**

*A locality in Alaska*

> [**NULATO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulato,_Alaska), a city in Alaska

*A film where a Chaplin performs*

> [**POLICE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_(1916_film)), a film starring Chaplin

*A meteorical medical condition*

> A **CRATER** may be assumed as a 'meteorical' medical condition

Comment: Amazing, feedback on question is right that there really exists a combination for everything. Ill updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

My second guess:

> **CALEMBOUR**

*A locality in Alaska*

> [**AMBLER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambler,_Alaska), city of Alaska

*A film where a Chaplin performs*

> [**CRUEL**, cruel love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruel,_Cruel_Love), a film that Chaplin *performs*

*A meteorical medical condition*

> I'm not sure what does meteorical mean but **CURABLE** is a medical condition.

*Find the word or die by sword*

> [**CALEMBOUR**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calembour) is the French of pun.